# setting postion of popover view in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am using a POPover View in my application where i have a action method,in that i am implementing popover view code.

I have a Button when i click on button popover View appears with table view,clicking on the cell the Cell data displays on the label.

What my requirement is when i click on the button the popover view is getting displayed on LEFT TOP corner,whereas button is Right Top Corner of the screen.i want to set the popover frame below the button on click so please correct me where i am going wrong.

```
    -(IBAction) settingsGo:(id) sender{

    NSLog(@"Go");

   if (self.popoverController == nil)

    {
        PopOver *lang = [[PopOver alloc]
                       initWithNibName:@"PopOver" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        UIPopoverController *popOver = 
        [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:lang];

        popOver.delegate = self;
        [lang release];

        self.popoverController = popOver;
        [popOver release];
    }
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(250, 150)];

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:Button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you can change the direction to UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown ...

Comment: @Steve Jobs yup i tried that as well its not working..

Comment: try [sender frame] instead of button.frame

Comment: I am goona re post it as an answer for others..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

this will do the trick..

Answer (score 3):

[**This**](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development) will help you out.

To set

```
UIButton *btnAction; // A button to which UIPopoverController will belong.
CGRect popoverFrame = btnAction.frame;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 355) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

**setPopoverContentSize** will set the size of UIPopoverController.

Comment: i am following this link only for my application..whereas in the above link when click on button the pop over view displays full screen which i dont want.i want pop over view to appear with particular frame size below the button

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ya i changed the above code still my button is right top corner when i click the pop over view is getting displayed left top corner..i want below the button.